# Tensorflow classification with extremely unbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow LinearClassifier and also DNN to classify two - classes dataset.

However, the problem is the dataset contains 96% of Positive output, and 4% of negative output, and my program always return the prediction as Positive. Of course, in this case I will achieved the accuracy of 96%, but it does not make sense at all.

What is the good way to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Use minority oversampling.

Comment: There have been several excellent answers, however I would like to signal this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data tutorial on tensorflow page

Answer (score 5):

You could try changing the cost function so that a false positive output would be penalized more heavily than a false negative.

Comment: Hi, in DNN, what type of activation function will give me this feature? Thanks

Comment: @mamatv It's not an activation function. The cost function is your optimization goal. Most of the time it is either cross-entropy (CE) or mean squared error (MSE)

Comment: When you do get enough rep could you delete this answer and make it a comment. I gave you an upvote to get you closer to 50 rep but don't want people to think I gave you an upvote because I consider this the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do, with the simplest solutions first:

1. You can construct minibatches that sample the classes equally and then re-calibrate the model at test time.
2. You can reweight the examples to favor the negatives
3. You can use a hinge loss instead of a log loss that might be more robust to the unbalanced data since it would get no gradient when an example is correct beyond the margin
4. You can explore some other loss function that treats the different types of errors asymetrically

Comment: Hi, I think I will start with weighted classes. Do you know how could I start with tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

You may learn an auto-encoder on the negative examples you have (if their number is kind of large) and then generate examples using an inference technique such as [variational Bayes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) or [Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume15/alain14a/alain14a.pdf). This way you can increase the number of samples for the negative examples and kind of move towards a more balanced data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this paper for different sampling techniques for mitigating class imbalance problem http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/62.pdf. Simple random minority oversampling usually works better.